# Трансляция звука с компьютера на телефон

Tags: python

Всем привет. Мне стало интересно, можно ли написать программу для трансляции звука с компьютера на телефон. Как это можно реализовать, используя язык программирования python?

Comment: Это и без программы, через блютус прекрасно можно сделать.

Comment: проблема в том что на python не пишут мобильные приложения. как вариант могу предложить использовать web технологии (html, css , js)